# It's possible to upload a movie via php sdk?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, sdk

How can i do it?

i tried something like $facebook->api('/me/movies','POST',array('source'=>..));

but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

see this howto: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/

Answer (score 1):

Accessing /me/movies is a list of the movies that the user likes.  Things that the user likes are not editable via the Facebook Graph API.  If you are trying to upload a movie file, you would use /me/videos.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proper solution. You need the access token from somewhere. In my case I get it into another moment. And I upload the video when the user is offline.

```
require 'php-sdk/src/facebook.php';
.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));

$facebook->setAccessToken("myaccesstokenhere");

$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$args = array('title' => 'The title of the video','description'=>'The description of the video');
$args['videoData'] = '@' . realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/video.mp4");


try {
    $data = $facebook->api('/me/videos', 'post', $args); 
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo "result=ERROR&message=".$e->getMessage();
                die();
}
```